# Get path of index.php relative to any script loaded

Tags: php

Eg : I have `localhost/crm/index.php?action=login`
or 
`localhost/live/crm/index.php?action=login`

Suppose I load another script eg : `logout.php` in url it becomes `localhost/crm/index.php?action=logout`

I want to get path of index.php like `crm` or `live/crm` respectively.

Comment: What you have tried??

Comment: $pg=substr(__DIR__,9);

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php

echo dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
<?php
$link=parse_url('http://localhost/live/crm/index.php?action=login')['path'];
echo substr($link,0,strrpos($link,'/'));
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
/live/crm
```